# Entity Framework: Retrieve data from multiple entities using generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository

I have created a Web API Project in which I am implementing a repository pattern. In a nutshell, I have the following structure.

```
Controller
    |
Business/Service Layer
    |
Repository
    |
DB-Access
```

Here is a code of one of my Service Layer:

```
public class DashboardService : IDashboardService
{   
    private readonly IRepository<USERROLE> repoUserRole;
    private readonly IRepository<ROLEEXT> repoRoleExt;  

    public void GetUserInstitution(string UserId)
    {
        repoUserRole.GetList(x => x.ID == UserId, null).Join(
            repoRoleExt.GetList(),
            uRole => uRole.ROLEID, roleEx => roleEx.ROLEID, (uRole, roleEx) => new
            {
                USERROLE = uRole,
                ROLEEXT = roleEx
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

`GetList` Method in Repository looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
{
    // Some code omitted
    public IEnumerable<T> GetList()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params string[] navigationProperties)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> list;
        var query = DbSet.AsQueryable();
        if (navigationProperties != null && navigationProperties.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(navigationProperty);
            }
        }
        list = query.Where(predicate).ToList<T>();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**What I want:**

- A Generic method which can take multiple entities(join them) and return the resultset. (Also where should that method be? (Business or Repo)

As seen in my code I have followed the following approach:

- Create Instance of Each Repository <=> Entity type object
- Using those objects retrieve data

**Problem:**

- Not sure if this is a correct approach of implementing the repository pattern!
- If not What would be the best way to handle this?

P.S.: I am aware of error present in the `GetUserInstitution` method.

***Edit***: Also, If not using Generic repository, do I have to create multiple repository based on Entites?

Comment: answered below, if you find the answer useful, please upvote. Cheers.

Comment: One big problem I see with your repository is that you are bringing entire tables into memory and joining them.  if you tables are large you are going to have major performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider just creating separate repositories with separate different contracts for each entity and not resort to trying to create a generic repository. Not all of your repositories will NEED to return a list, and it doesnt make sense to have repositories that dont implement methods to have boilerplate NotImplementedExceptions or things like that. 
Instead, follow the approach taken my many engineers of just creating separate contracts/interfaces for each repository. 
It may appear that creating a single generic repository would be following the SRP rule, but after you begin creating more and more repositories, youll begin to see some idiosyncratic attributes of the repositories, and in the end your just better of without generic repository.

One case for creating an interface for a repository class is as follows

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
```

Then, you would use it as

```
    public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
Order Add(Order order);
// ...
}
```

IAggregateRoot above is the marker interface pattern.

Honestly, I would just start out with different contracts per repository, and later if it makes sense to add the IRepository, do so.

Comment: From the [definition](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) of repository pattern from PofEAA >Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.  if you're repository isn't returning a collection is it really a repository?

Comment: The questions seems unrelated to my post above